# What keeps a browser request from being redirected due to improper CORS handling?

Tags: javascript, redirect, paypal, cors, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate digital payment oauth into my app, but I'm having trouble with the redirects these services require. Both PayPal and Stripe require a redirect to their site for approval before redirecting back to my site. But my browser is blocks the redirects to the pay services because, it claims, there are no access-control-allow-origin headers present. Yet I know for a fact that Stripe supports CORS headers: https://stripe.com/blog/stripejs-and-jsonp. What could I be doing wrong?

**Importantly**, if I manually type the desired uri on my server (localhost.com/authorize) into my browser, the browser redirects just fine, but if the script in my client performs a GET request to the same URI, the browser rejects the redirect with this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load
connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin '127.0.0.1:3000' is therefore not allowed
access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Therefore, the only difference between a manual GET request using the browser address bar and the programmatic GET request using ajax is what the browser recognizes as the *initiator* of the request. Why does the initiator determine the success or failure of this action?

I'm performing a jquery ajax request from my client to my server like so:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/authorize',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
          // do something
        }.bind(this),
        error: function() {
            // do something
        }.bind(this)
    });
```

I'm using the [example code from stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts) to perform the authorization and redirects:

```
app.get('/authorize', function(req, res) {
  // Redirect to Stripe /oauth/authorize endpoint
  res.redirect(AUTHORIZE_URI + '?' + qs.stringify({
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'read_write',
    client_id: CLIENT_ID
  }));
});
```

Comment: Usually a web service that has CORS support requires from you to set them the domains from which the AJAX calls will come. You might need to add `127.0.0.1` (or `127.0.0.1:3000`) to your configuration so that Stripe accepts requests from that domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting the user to get redirected to Stripe or Paypal during or after the ajax request you can't issue the redirect on the ajax request itself. Within the ajax context you are just redirecting the ajax request which is why you see the CORS errors.

To redirect the window you would need your `app.get('/authorize'...` to return back the redirect URL.

Then in your `$.ajax` success function you could set the window location: `window.location = data.redirectUri` or open a new window(ugh).